# doing if else in a loop with arrays rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

currently am getting bunch of records from database and wrapping those records in an array but i want to set an if condition within it

```
@reports = SnapshotReport.includes(camera: [:user]).where(report_date: date)
records = []
@reports.each do |report|
  next if report.camera.cloud_recording.blank?
  records[records.length] = [
    report.camera["name"],
    report.camera["exid"],
    report.camera.user["firstname"],
    report.camera.cloud_recording["storage_duration"],
    report.camera["is_online"],
    report["snapshot_count"],
    report.camera["id"],
    report.camera.user["id"],
    report.camera.user["lastname"],
  ]
end
```

right now what am doing is , using `next if` to skip such values where

```
next if report.camera.cloud_recording.blank?
```

is null, but i want to do this thing array making portion but like that 
if `report.camera.cloud_recording` is null then it saves an `""` empty string but if report.camera.cloud_recording is present then get the value of `report.camera.cloud_recording["storage_duration"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@reports = SnapshotReport.includes(camera: [:user]).where(report_date: date)
records = []
@reports.each do |report|
  records[records.length] = [
    report.camera["name"],
    report.camera["exid"],
    report.camera.user["firstname"],
    report.camera.cloud_recording || {"storage_duration" => ""} ["storage_duration"],
    report.camera["is_online"],
    report["snapshot_count"],
    report.camera["id"],
    report.camera.user["id"],
    report.camera.user["lastname"],
  ]
end
```